# Math function in python not working when creating a python.exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using this in cmd to create a .exe python file to run on PC.

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification --onefile abc.pyw
```

However, after which the program gets executed, math function is not working. While the program gets executed properly when run on cmd as a python file.

Is there any specific import which is required.?

Please help me out.

Comment: What happens? What is the error message, if any?

Comment: There is no such error message, function is being used to ignore the NaN (blank spaces) while reading an excel. When i run the code on cmd, it works properly ignoring NaN values. But when run on exe, displays NaN as output.

Comment: Have you tried to pack it without `-w` to see the error in the console?

Comment: uh, sorry kevin.... I did not get what you said....